# Probability of standard normal greater than another standard normal conditional on truncation

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

$X,Y \sim N(0,1)$ independently. Find $P(Y > 3X | Y >  0)$. My attempt:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y > 3X | Y > 0) &=& P(X < Y/3 | Y > 0) \\
&=& E(1(X < Y/3)| Y > 0) \\
&=& E\big(E(1(X < y/3) | Y=y)| Y > 0\big) \\
&=& E\big(P(X < y/3) | Y>0 \big) \quad \because X \perp Y \\
&=& E(\Phi(Y/3) | Y>0)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Is there any way to get a closed form expression for this? I know how to get $E(\Phi(aY + b))$ but getting the expectation over a truncated normal distribution seems elusive.

Comment: Hint: draw a picture of this event and bear in mind that $(X,Y)$ is rotationally symmetric around the origin.

Comment: I believe this one is already answered on site.

Answer (score 0):

Graphical comment: @whuber's picture.

```
## a million points for 2-3 digits of accuracy
set.seed(319)
X = rnorm(10^6); Y = rnorm(10^6)
mean(Y > 3*X & Y > 0)
[1] 0.300751
mean(Y > 3*X & Y > 0)/mean(Y > 0)
[1] 0.6027038

## Fewer points for figure
x = X[1:50000];  y= Y[1:50000]
plot(x,y, pch=".")
 abline(a = 0, b = 3, col="green", lwd=2)
 abline(h=0, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice work--but because the question focuses on the condition $Y\gt 0,$ don't you think it would be better to plot only the upper half plane of this figure?

Comment: @whuber. Or at least given a note to look there, which you have now done. (I guess I showed the whole thing because you mentioned rotation about the origin.)